# Fixing redirect loop in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have spent some time on google and here, searching away but I still haven't been able to resolve my dilema.

I am currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ty [L]

http://www.site.com/ **Works**
http://www.site.com **Works**
http://site.com/ **Redirect Loop**
http://site.com **Redirect Loop**
https://www.site.com/ **Works**
https://www.site.com **Works**
```

Can anyone help me with my RewriteCond to get rid of the loop?

The final result should be http://site.com/ty/ [rest of url]
**Not** http://site.com/ty/ty/ty/ty/ty/ty/ty/ty/ty/

Comment: Can you explain the final result you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ ty [L]
```

Comment: Seems to be working! I tried that earlier but maybe it was just cached. Thanks.